# Write universal quantifier in terms of existential quantifier

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

By definition I have learned that:

$ (\exists x)B \mbox{ stands for }(\lnot((\forall x)(\lnot B)))
$

But in a logical proof I need the identity:

$(\forall x) B \mbox{ stands for } (\lnot((\exists x)\lnot B))
$
Can I just derive this identity or need I prove it (with the axioms, modus ponens, generalization or the deduction theorem)?

In the last case, it is hard. Since it seems so trivial, I can't think of a clever way to prove it, other than claiming it is trivial, but in logic everything needs explanation..

Comment: $\forall x (B(x)) \equiv  \lnot\lnot \forall x (B(x)) \equiv \lnot \exists x (\lnot B(x))$

Comment: Alternatively, $(\exists x A) \implies b \quad \equiv \quad \forall x (A \implies b)$ is a more constructive way to relate the two.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\forall x) B = \neg(\neg((\forall x) \neg(\neg(B)))) = \neg((\exists x) \neg B))$$